# hibernate annotation- inheritance with @MappedSuperclass - values are not being set to base class fields- strange error

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa, annotations

I was following  [Hibernate: Use a Base Class to Map Common Fields](http://ocpsoft.org/java/hibernate-use-a-base-class-to-map-common-fields/)   and  [openjpa inheritance tutorial](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_inher.html)   to put common columns like ID, lastModifiedDate etc in base table.

My annotated mappings are as follow :

**BaseTable :**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseTable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "lastmodifieddate")
    private Date lastModifiedDate;
...
```

**Person table -**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Person ")
    public class Person extends BaseTable  implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
...
```

**Create statement generated :**

```
create table Person (id integer not null auto_increment,  lastmodifieddate datetime, name varchar(255), primary key (id)) ;
```

After I save a Person object to db,

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Test");
p.setLastModifiedDate(new Date());
..

getSession().save(p);
```

I am setting the date field but, it is saving the record with generated ID and LastModifiedDate = null, and Name="Test".

**Insert Statement :**

```
insert into Person (lastmodifieddate, name) values (?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - <null>
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - Test
```

**Read by ID query :**
When I do hibernate query (get By ID) as below, It reads person by given ID.

```
Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(Person.class);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
Person person= c.list().get(0);
//person has generated ID, LastModifiedDate is null

select query select person0_.id as id8_,  person0_.lastmodifieddate as lastmodi8_, person0_.name as name8_ from Person person0_
 - Found [1] as column [id8_]
 - Found [null] as column [lastmodi8_]
 - Found [Test] as column [name8_ ]
```

**ReadAll query :**

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("from " + Person.class.getName());
List<Person> allPersons=query.list();
```

Corresponding SQL for read all

```
select query select person0_.id as id8_,  person0_.lastmodifieddate as lastmodi8_, person0_.name as name8_ from Person person0_
- Found [1] as column [id8_]
- Found [null] as column [lastmodi8_]
- Found [Test] as column [name8_ ]
- Found [2] as column [id8_]
- Found [null] as column [lastmodi8_]
- Found [Test2] as column [name8_ ]
```

But when I print out the list in console, its being more weird.  it is selecting List of Person object with

- ID fields = all 0 (why all 0 ?)
- LastModifiedDate = null
- Name fields have valid values

I don't know whats wrong here. Could you please look at it?

**FYI,**

My Hibernate-core version : 4.1.2, MySQL Connector version : 5.1.9 .

**In summary, There are two issues here**

- Why I am getting All ID Fields =0 when using read all?
- Why the LastModifiedDate is not being inserted?

Comment: What type ща 'lastmodifieddate' in DB?

Comment: Its `datetime` . The mapping is generating the columns in DB Table properly.

Comment: For `id`, what persistence provider are you using?

Comment: <provider> in persistence.xml. HibernatePersistance?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. I don't have any persistence.xml file. I am using Spring+Hibernate and Annotation for mapping the persistent objects. Could you please tell me what's the `persistence provider` you are talking about?

Comment: what is the db used? can you provide the table create query, also you can enable hibernate query logging, can you see the queries that are executed

Comment: @SubinS, Its MySQL. I have posted the generated queries after logging. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
```

annotation on `Date`

For ID generation use strategy.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

or

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

or using sequance

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "custom_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "custom_generator", sequenceName = "sequance_table")
```

also you can make property access in your child class:

```
public abstract class BaseTable {

    protected int id;

    protected Date lastModifiedDate;  
// ...  
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person extends BaseTable  implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
public getId()
{
   return super.id;
}

setId(log id)
{
   super.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "lastmodifieddate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) 
public getLastModifiedDate()
{
   return super.lastModifiedDate;
}

setLastModifiedDate(Date date)
{
   super.lastModifiedDate = date;
}

public getName()
// ...
}
```

Comment: I tried all you suggested, but it is still the same.. thanks.

Comment: Date still isn't inserted too?

Comment: updated, without @MappedSuperclass, but same idea. If still not working, then I can't help...

Answer (score 0):

Try this out in BaseTable class

```
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "lastmodifieddate", nullable = false,
        columnDefinition = "Timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
public Date getLastModifiedDate( )
{
  return this.lastModifiedDate;
}
```

where BaseTable class should have @MappedSuperclass. And there must be one generated date field in an entity.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseTable {

    protected int id;

    protected Date lastModifiedDate;  


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) // For Mysql
    // For Oracle or MSSQL @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId()
    {
      return this.id;
    }


    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "lastmodifieddate", nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "Timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    public Date getLastModifiedDate( )
    {
      return this.lastModifiedDate;
    }



}
```